# How to divide page to sections by DIV?

Tags: html

I want to divide my page in to two section using DIV tag, but the output is not correct.  
This is my code:  
  
...

```
<body>
   <div style="float:right; width: 20ex;background-color:red;">
       my menu content....
   </div>
   <div style="background-color:green;">
         <table style="width:100%; border-style:solid;border-width:5px; border-color:yellow;">
             <tr><td>some content...</td></tr>
         </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

The right div not starts at end of left div and the end of table is out of left div. The table's width should be same the rigth div but it's width is same as page width.  
The right div is menu holder and should be fixed width (20ex) and the left div is my content section and should fill the rest of page width.  
I can't set fixed width to left div.  
What is wrong?

Comment: you specified width:100%;, and the right div only has 20px

Comment: This question needs some more information in order to be answerable. To which elements do you want to set a fixed width, and which elements should they be? What should the width of each element be?

Comment: the right div is menu holder and should be fixed width and the left div is my content section and should fill the rest of page width

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is:

```
<body>
   <div style="float:right; width: 20ex;background-color:red;inline;width:50%;">
      my menu content....
   </div>
   <div style="float:right; background-color:green;display:inline;width:50%;">
      <table style="width:100%; border-style:solid;border-width:5px; border-color:yellow;">
         <tr><td>some content...</td></tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

[try it](http://jsfiddle.net/dgSf4/) and tell me if thats what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
   <div style="float:right; width: 100px;background-color:red;">
       my menu content....
   </div>
   <div style="background-color:green;">
         <table style="margin-right:105px; border-style:solid; border-width:5px; border-color:yellow;">
             <tr><td>some content...</td></tr>
         </table>
   </div>
</body>
```